# change style if two conditions are true

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, if-statement

I have a small app that should get two price values from elements on a website.
This is achieved by iterating over the `.textContent` of the two querySelectors (cardStartBidValueString  and cardCurrentBidValuesString).
Then I also get all elements with a specific CSS selector (cardBg).

What I want to do is to check if the start price and the current bid price are both < userInputBidPrice (which is the cap of what a user wants to bid) and if this is true, then change the background color of that item so the user can directly see a potential deal. In sum there are 20 elemenets that include those two prices. So basically I want to change the background of all elements for which above condition is true.

Unfortunately its nor working. if I say `cardBg[i].style['background-color'] = '#0311c3'`then it only changes the color when the CurrentBidPrice is < userInputBidPrice and if I change it to `cardBg[x].style['background-color'] = '#0311c3'` then it colors all item if the startBidPrice is < userInputBidPrice

For some reason it is not checking if both conditions are true.

This is my code:

```
function deals() {
    let userInputBidPrice = prompt('Set max Bid Price:');
    let cardCurrentBidValuesString = document.querySelectorAll('.auction > .auctionValue:nth-child(2) > .currency-coins.value');
    let cardStartBidValueString = document.querySelectorAll('.auction > .auctionStartPrice.auctionValue > .currency-coins.value');
    let cardBg = document.querySelectorAll('.rowContent.has-tap-callback');

    for (let i = 0; i < cardCurrentBidValuesString.length; i++) {
        cardsCurrentBidPrice = cardCurrentBidValuesString[i].textContent.toString().split(',').join('');

        if (cardsCurrentBidPrice === '---') {
            cardsCurrentBidPrice = 0;
        }
        parsedCardsCurrentBidPrice = parseInt(cardsCurrentBidPrice);

        for (let x = 0; x < cardStartBidValueString.length; x++) {
            cardsStartBidPrice = cardStartBidValueString[x].textContent.toString().split(',').join('');
            if (cardsStartBidPrice === '---') {
                cardsStartBidPrice = 0;
            }
            parsedCardsStartBidPrice = parseInt(cardsStartBidPrice);
        }

        if (parsedCardsCurrentBidPrice < parseInt(userInputBidPrice) && parsedCardsStartBidPrice < parseInt(userInputBidPrice)) {
            cardBg[i].style['background-color'] = '#0311c3';
        }
    }
}

deals();
```

Comment: There's no need to call `toString()` on the result of `textContent`: it's always a string.

Comment: Did you debug your code in devtools? Single-step through it and look at variables? Evaluate parts of the condition etc. when the line was reached, to understand why it does what it does? What did you find?

Comment: Please provide an example of the HTML on which this code runs.